# Quicker method to map values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df (`df1`) containing no more than 10 rows. It displays two reference columns (`Val1, Val2`) and a third column (`Item`) that represents an important string. I have a second data frame that contains the same reference columns (`Val1, Val2`) but more than 5 million rows. I want to map  `Item` from the initial df to the second data frame in an efficient manner.

I've tried `merge` or setting the index and using `join`. `Dask` did not speed up the process either. Is there a separate method I can use instead of merging/joining the two data frames?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Val1' : [1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0],    
    'Val2' : ['Red','Blue','Red','Blue'],       
    'Item' : ['Up','Down','Down','Up'],                                  
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Val1' : [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0],  
    'Val2' : ['Red','Blue','Red','Blue','Red','Blue','Red','Blue'],                                      
    })

df1.set_index(['Val1','Val2'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Val1','Val2'], inplace=True)

df_final = df2.join(df1, how = 'left').reset_index()
```

Comment: `df2.merge(df1, on=['Val1','Val2'], how='left')` should be pretty fast, even for a million rows. Took about 120 ms when `len(df2)==800k`.

Comment: In contrast, `df2.join(df1, how = 'left').reset_index()` takes 400ms not counting the time for `set_index`.

Comment: It's around 5 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, integer keys result in faster merge times. For this, you can map `Val1` and `Val2` to integers on both dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) and then merge by `Val1` and `Val2`.

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to map `Val1` and `Val2` to integers, but the purpose of this answer is to show that merging on integers is faster.

```py
# Turn Val1 and Val2 to categorical dtypes
df2[['Val1','Val2']] = df2[['Val1','Val2']].apply(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x))
# Turn categories to dictionaries
d1 = dict(enumerate(df2['Val1'].cat.categories))
d2 = dict(enumerate(df2['Val2'].cat.categories))
# Reverse keys and values in each dictionary
d1 = {v:k for k,v in d1.items()}
d2 = {v:k for k,v in d2.items()}
# Replace columns in df1
df1['Val1'].replace(d1, inplace=True)
df2['Val1'].replace(d1, inplace=True)
df1['Val2'].replace(d2, inplace=True)
df2['Val2'].replace(d2, inplace=True)
# Merge by integer versions of Val1 and Val2
df2.merge(df1, on=['Val1','Val2'], how='left')
```

Comparison of execution times:

```
# Merge with original keys
start = time.time()
df2.merge(df1, on=['Val1','Val2'], how='left')
round(time.time() - start, 5)

0.00672

# Merge with integer keys
start = time.time()
df2.merge(df1, on=['Val1','Val2'])
round(time.time() - start, 5)

0.00485
```